# Laravel command fails on cPanel only

Tags: laravel, cpanel, laravel-artisan

I have a command where I find some models and send emails. I'm not gonna post the whole code but simply it looks like this.

` Log::info('Daily Late  Requests Check Executed!');
$newRequests=ModelsRequest::where("status","pending")->get();

```
    foreach ($newRequests as $request){
   
     Http::get('url', [
     //parameters//
     ]);

     Mail::to($request->donorEmail)->send(new donorLateReq([
     //parameters//
     ])); 
 } `
```

I have added this command on Kernal.php and this works fine when I run php artisan schedule:run on my localhost.

But on my cpanel it only executes this line.

`Log::info('Daily Late Requests Check Executed!');`

I guess this line can't be executed on cpanel.

`ModelsRequest::where("status","pending")->get();`

All models are working fine on every controller. The whole app works fine on cpanel except this scheduled command.

I tried sending an email, sending an sms using this scheduled command and those worked fine.

Anyone knows how to fix this on cPanel?

Thanks!

Tried running a scheduled laravel command on cpanel

Comment: Can you go to `phpmyadmin` and check your table if there's status `pending` there? Maybe there's no data there.

Comment: There are rows with pending status. Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: Well... on cPanel you'll have to do `dd($newRequests);`, because somethings different from your local installation. I would also do random `dump();` in your code on cPanel